# pythonスクレイピングにて一部しかcsvに書き込まれない・・？

Tags: python, web-scraping

こんにちは
ご覧いただきましてありがとうございます。

pythonを活用したスクレイピングの件で、質問させていただきます。

■質問内容
web上から競馬の出馬表をスクレイピングしておりますが、一部しかcsvに書き込まれておりません。
スクレイピングを行なった結果、出馬表の表頭部分（馬名・枠番といった列名）しかcsvには書き込まれておらず、
馬の名前や厩舎、オッズなどがcsvに書き込まれておりません。

以下に参照しているページとコードを記載いたしますので
御確認いただくと幸いです。

> import csv  
>   from urllib.request import urlopen  
>   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>
> ## URLの指定
>
> html = urlopen("http://race.netkeiba.com/?pid=race&id=c201605050211&mode=shutuba")
>   bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>
> ## テーブルを指定
>
> table = bsObj.findAll("table",{"class":"race_table_01 nk_tb_common shutuba_table"})[0] 
>   rows = table.findAll("tr")
>
> csvFile = open("shutuba.csv", 'wt', newline = '', encoding =
>   'shift_jis') 
>   writer = csv.writer(csvFile) 
>   try:  for row in rows:  
>   csvRow = []   
>   for cell in row.findAll(['th', 'td']):
>    csvRow.append(cell.get_text())   
>   writer.writerow(csvRow) 
>   finally:
>       csvFile.close()

このようにターミナル上へ入力するとcsvは作成されるのですが、
表の上部分のみで、肝心の馬の名前などは情報が書き込まれておりません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

おそらくスクレイピングのコマンド自体ではなく、
csv書き込み時のコマンドがあまり良くないのかと
推察をしているのですが、何をやってもうまくいかず
皆様の知識をお借りしたいと思います。

コマンドで修正すべきポイントなど、教えて頂けますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく`for`部分のインデントが間違っています。
あとENCODEを`utf-8`に変えた方が良いとエラー文がでました。
下記コピペでCSVファイルが生成されます。

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = urlopen("http://race.netkeiba.com/?pid=race&id=c201605050211&mode=shutuba")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


table = bsObj.findAll("table",{"class":"race_table_01 nk_tb_common shutuba_table"})[0]
rows = table.findAll("tr")

csvFile = open("shutuba.csv", 'wt', newline = '', encoding ='utf-8')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
try:
    for row in rows:
        csvRow = []
        for cell in row.findAll(['th', 'td']):
            csvRow.append(cell.get_text())
            writer.writerow(csvRow)
finally:
    csvFile.close()
```

追伸
スタックオーバーフローでコードをコーティングするにはコード部分を選択して上の{}でできます。

Comment: ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。
ENCODEですが私のPCがmacを活用しており、utf-8を使うと
文字化けしてしまう事があったので、shift-jisに変更をしております。

いただきましたスクリプトのencodeをshift-jisに変更すると
文字化けは解消しましたが、一部のみ書き込まれている状況でした。。